# save Student using hibernate with current date and dob and enum

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

[image]

and so far i have made bean class like that

```
    import javax.persistence.Column;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;

    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;

    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

    import javax.persistence.Id;

    import javax.persistence.Table;

    import lombok.Getter;

    import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

    import lombok.Setter;

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Entity
    @Table(name="logintableetech")

public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="student_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="full_name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="bebo_reg_id")
    private String regId;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
}
```

Please help me to choose which class should i use for appropariate date ,i want birthdate as date entered by user and date_registed for date as current timestamp and also tell me how to save for enum in databse for mysql what data type should i use String (if possible) or Enum.

Comment: i got the answer now i have to use the temporal annotation but still i am having problem in enum